# Css Transform scale does not work on modal card popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I saw lots of modal based questions in stackoverflow, so it might looks similar questions to other stackover-flow question, but the design I am looking for did not find anywhere. That's why I am asking this question. I am really new in designing. I like [Instagram modal card popup when user click the image](https://www.instagram.com/bbc/). I think they have used `transform:scale()` and I try to implement that logic but seems like it does not work. I want the card grow `scale` 1.2 to 1.I have share my code in snippet. If anyone show me how to do that modal card popup like instagram I will be really glad.

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("modal-container");
  const btn = document.getElementById("open-modal-button");
  const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.classList.add("visible");
  };

  span.onclick = function () {
    modal.classList.remove("visible");
  };

  document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
      modal.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  });
```

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: none;
  }

  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(60, 75, 100, 0.14);
    display:none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .visible {
   display: block;
   transform: scale(1);
  }

  .visible > .modal-content {
    display: block;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Instagram Modal popup</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="open-modal-button">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-container" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you even toggle the display property from none to block, your transition on other elements will not occur.

You could add a class with a delayed JS call, or..

If your enviroment allows to rely on keyframe animations: Put all the other transitions into a keyframe animation and it works! \o/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes scale {
      0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(1.3); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}
@-moz-keyframes scale{
      0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(1.3); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: tscale(1);}
}
```

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("modal-container");
  const btn = document.getElementById("open-modal-button");
  const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.classList.add("visible");
  };

  span.onclick = function () {
    modal.classList.remove("visible");
  };

  document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
      modal.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  });
```

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: none;
  }

  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(60, 75, 100, 0.14);
    display:none;
  }

  .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .visible {
   display: block;
  }

  .visible > .modal-content {
    display: block;
   -webkit-animation: scale .3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: scale .3s ease-out;
  }
  
  
@-webkit-keyframes scale {
      0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(1.3); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}
@-moz-keyframes scale{
      0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(1.3); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: tscale(1);}
}
```

```html
<h2>Instagram Modal popup</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="open-modal-button">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-container" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```